# Returning struct from different file in C

Tags: c, gcc, struct, return-value

Lately I've encountered a problem of returning struct from another file in C language.
Here's the code of main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hash_types.h"


int main()
{
    hashinfo info;

    info = numerator();

    printf("%d\n", info.ppower);

return 0;
}
```

And numerator.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hash_types.h"

hashinfo numerator()
{
    hashinfo info;

    info.ppower = 15;

return info;
}
```

Here's what header file looks like:

```
typedef struct hashinfo{

    unsigned long a_str;
    unsigned long a_int;
    unsigned long b_int;
    unsigned long p;
    unsigned long m;
    char w;
    char ppower;
}hashinfo;
```

When I try to compile the code, gcc fails to compile `main` reporting that

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘hashinfo’ from type 'int'
  info = numerator();
       ^
```

If I put all of these in the one file and compile, it will work just fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a prototype of `numerator` in `hash_types.h` ?

Comment: How does `main()` know what the return type of `numerator()` is (or that it even exists)?

Comment: Put "hashinfo numerator();" in hash_types.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare your `numerator` function everywhere where you want to use it. This is what the minimal declaration would look like

```
hashinfo numerator();
```

But a better idea would be to declare it with prototype

```
hashinfo numerator(void);
```

and do the same thing in the definition.

A typical approach would be to put the declaration into a header file and include it everywhere you what to use this function. Whether your `hash_types.h` is the appropriate one is for you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

So how do you think that the main.c part (top) would know what type that numerator() returned? How would you inform main.c that it will reference functions of specific signatures?  Potentially, you could create a separate file containing nothing but prototypes for your functions and have all modules include it. "proto.h" or similar.

Mark

Comment: Add some more content

Comment: I was hoping my response would prompt his discovery . . .

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to telling your main what `numerator()` returns without including it somehow. It's generally considered bad practice to include a `.c` file, but try to add `#include "numerator.c"` to the top of `main.c` to see.

Answer (score 0):

Add the declaration for `numerator()` in the header file `hash_types.h`. Add this at the end of `hash_types.h`: `hashinfo numerator();`